# Django rest framework extremly slow (recursive relations)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For my project I started to use Laravel for the api than I switched to Django / django rest framework, I did this to gain more speed as I need to query large data.

Now I got the following situation:
I got a "Group" which has "Subjects" and which has a recursive relation.

Now a group can have like 2000+ subjects(including the descendent subjects) a parent subject has +/- 30 subjects.

This is my code:

**serializers**

```
class RecursiveField(serializers.Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        serializer = self.parent.parent.__class__(value, context=self.context)
        return serializer.data

class SubjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent_of = RecursiveField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields = ("id", "name", "parent_of", "parent")

class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subjects = SubjectSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ("id", "name", "subjects")

    def setup_eager_loading(cls, queryset):
        return queryset.prefetch_related("subjects")
```

**views**

```
class GroupViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    class Paginator(BasePaginator):
        model = Group

    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.GroupSerializer
    pagination_class = Paginator

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.get_serializer().setup_eager_loading(GroupViewSet.queryset)
```

I tested the same request with the laravel api and its much faster, still noticeable slow but its ok(5-10 secs). With django rest framework its too slow (1 minute +/-), and thats just a page with 1 group that has 2500 subjects.

I do know what takes long, the RecursiveField class, because when I remove that the query is done in less than 2 seconds. So my question is whats the main cause, because it's creates a recursive relation (I doubt)? Or is it because I don't prefetch?

And ofcourse whats the best way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at django-mptt for your Subject model.  It's very stable https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, but I don't think any are great. Recursive queries aren't very well supported with Django.

1. Rework your data model to prevent needing to use recursion to fetch the subjects from the database. You could add a `root` ForeignKey to Subject on Subject that would identify the root subject. This would allow you to grab all subjects in a tree fairly easily. Then you'd have to arrange them in your View/Viewset to fit the ordering (if that's necessary).
2. Use `raw()` and your database's recursive functionality to fetch the models. This would require raw SQL and can be painful to maintain.
3. Use `django_cte`. I've used this in one of my projects for a few queries, but I'm not a big fan of it. It breaks some functionality with `update()` being called on an empty queryset. However, it will work and it won't require you to drop down to raw SQL.

Comment: I am still convinced that a recursive relation is normal in a datastructure. But i've changed the data structure and it seems to not help, I don't know what django rest framework is doing but it is very slow at handling large data that have no relations at all... For example if I want to retrieve all the subjects of a group it takes like 20-30 seconds to load...

Comment: Add Django Debug Toolbar and see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not DRF, but the data structure itself.

It is very slow in `django` to query all ancestors/descendants recursively, your should use a more efficient data structure.

For the same reason I wrote `django-treenode`, it performs tree operations without query the db.
You can read the docs here: https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/django-treenode